# LaTeX Tikz: Compare two \def arguments

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, comparison

I am writing a macro definition that draws dimensions in the style of technical drawing. I need to perform an inequality of two of the arguments to know which is coordinate is higher up, but the console doesn't understand the condition I used as the **\ifthenelse** argument.

```
%   (#1,#2):    Starting coordinate
%   (#3,#4):    Ending coordinate
%   #5:         Vertical upwards distance from the body
%   #6:         Dimension text
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\def\DimensionTop(#1,#2)(#3,#4)[#5,#6]{
    \ifthenelse{#2>#4}
    {   %   If point (#1,#2) is higher than (#3,#4)
        \coordinate (D1) at ($ (#1,#2) + (0,#5) $);
        \coordinate (D2) at ($ (#3,#4) + (0,#2-#4) + (0,#5) $);
    }
    {   %   If point (#3,#4) is higher than (#1,#2)
        \coordinate (D1) at ($ (#1,#2) + (0,#4-#2) + (0,#5) $);
        \coordinate (D2) at ($ (#3,#4) + (0,#5) $);
    }
    \draw (#1,#2) -- (D1) -- ++(0,0.2);
    \draw (#3,#4) -- (D2) -- ++(0,0.2);
    \draw[ , >=latex, thin ] (D1) -- (D2) node[ fill=white, midway ] {$\mathtt{#6}$};
}
```

The function is used like this in the main document

```
\documentclass[border=2pt,convert={outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        % Custom command for the background grid, ignore
        \GuideCartesian(-2,-2)(8,8);

        \draw[ very thick ] (0,4) -- (2,5);
        \DimensionTop(0,4)(2,5)[1,1.50];

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Since the console doesn't understand the condition, it goes directly to the **else** case, which works when the point on the right is higher than the point on the left as in the picture.

[image: Horizontal Dimension]

What would be a correct way to express this condition?

Comment: Don't show only snippets. Make a complete example, that makes testing much easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to compute the maximum of two y coordinates. Since you are using `calc`, you may just do

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/dimension top/.style={code={
     \tikzset{dimension top/.cd,#1}
     \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dimension top/##1}}%  
     \draw
     let \p1=\pv{first},\p2=\pv{second},\n1={max(\y1,\y2)} in
     (\x1,\y1) -- (\x1,\n1+0.2cm) (\x2,\y2) -- (\x2,\n1+0.2cm) 
     (\x1,\n1) -- node[above,midway]{\pv{text}} (\x2,\n1) ;}},
     dimension top/.cd,first/.initial={(0,0)},second/.initial={(1,0)},
     text/.initial=]
  \draw (0,4) -- (2,5);
  \pic{dimension top={first={(0,4)},second={(2,5)},text=1.5}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]